# How do you change the current user control based on a ViewModel field in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I'm trying to code a dungeon crawler where a player navigates between set locations. Only the location where the player is will be displayed on screen, and will be changed whenever the player moves to a new location.

My GameView currently consists of a UserControl displaying inventory,stats and the location. I was hoping to add the location to the centre of the screen as a second UserControl inside the GameView, and change it to another UserControl whenever the View is notified that the player has moved locations.

This is what I am currently using to change between user controls inside the main window to navigate through menus:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MenuViewModel}">
                <views:MenuView/>
            </DataTemplate>
             ...

        </ContentControl.Resources>
    </ContentControl>
```

I was hoping to use something similar for the location, but for some reason the location doesn't display at the centre of the screen:

```
       <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentLocation}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type locationModel:SmallRoom}">
                        <locationView:SmallRoomView/>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type locationModel:LargeRoom}">
                        <locationView:LargeRoomView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </Viewbox>
```

I have checked and the CurrentLocation attribute is being updated and is of the type SmallRoom. I have also checked to see how the code runs without the data templates...

```
        <ContentControl>
            <locationView:SmallRoomView/>
        </ContentControl>
```

...but not even this displays the UserControl in the centre of the screen. I've spent hours looking for bugs and have struggled to find any myself. Any suggestions of why my second UserControl is not displaying would be greatly appreciated. If there's any better way of doing this, advice would be appreciated. I'm fairly new to MVVM and WPF so go easy on me ;)

Comment: If you temporarily change that viewbox to a grid. What happens?

Comment: It's the same result - GUI displays with everything but the location UserControl

Comment: Is everything compiling?  Any errors at all in your output window?  Is it really displaying but somehow tiny or not particularly noticeable? You put something you'd see in that view?  Use snoop ( which I prefer BTW ) or the built in Debug > Windows > Live Visual Tree  and check you don't really have a view there.

Comment: Thanks, I'd never noticed that was an option. The Live Visual Tree shows that the location UserControl is showing. I'm guessing that, since the location is composed of a grid of images, that the images aren't displaying? I'll see if the bug's there

Comment: It's running smoothly now. I hadn't noticed that the background image was displaying over the top of the UserControl. Thanks for the help